# What is Color3:lerp?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have been trying to fool around with its, and it's not working, here's my code:

```
color = Color3.new(math.random(255),math.random(255),math.random(255))
print(color)
script.Parent.BackgroundColor3:lerp(color,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Color3:lerp` is a way to interpolate between two `Color3` values. It's basically the `CFrame:lerp` of `Color3`.

The reason the code you provided is not working is because you have the `Delta` argument of `lerp` set to 0. Here's an example on how to use it properly:

```
local newColor = Color3.new(math.random(255), math.random(255), math.random(255))
for i=0,1,0.1 do
    script.Parent.BackgroundColor3 = script.Parent.BackgroundColor3:lerp(newColor, i)
    wait()
end
```